# Как можно сделать код чище?

Tags: javascript

Создаю с помощью JS таблицу. Присваиваю циклом повторяющиеся стили и атрибуты. Прошу, подскажите можно ли упростить мой код?

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll("th");

if(elements) {
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].classList.add("align-top");
    elements[i].setAttribute("scope", "col");
    elements[i].setAttribute("role", "button");

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта проверка лишняя, т.к. `querySelectorAll` всегда возвращает `NodeList`

```
if(elements) { 
   // ...
}
```

`for-i` можно заменить на `for-of`

```
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   // ...
}
```

так попроще

```
for (const element of elements) {
   // ...
}
```

а лучше пойти еще дальше и вызвать на объекте `NodeList` метод `forEach` и туда передать обработчик элементов.

```
document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(function(element) {
    // ...
})
```

Заодно получится избавиться от лишних присваиваний и проверок

```
let elements = // ...
```

С атрибутами двоякая ситуация...
Если бы их было больше то, однозначно стоило бы ввести вспомогательную функцию, которая вставляет атрибуты по json'у:

```
function setAttributes(el, attrs) {
  for(var key in attrs) {
    el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
  }
}
```

и потом вызвать...
тогда получилось бы

```
document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(function(element) {
    setAttributes(element, {
        class: "align-top", 
        scope: "col", 
        role: "button"});
})
```

но c объявлением функции то, то на то и выходит... было бы больше атрибутов или нужно было бы это чаще делать - стоило бы попробовать

> **Замечание:**
> Как и следует из названия, функция `setAttributes` устанавливает атрибуты, а **не модифицирует их**. Соответственно, нужно быть аккуратнее с использованием данной функции вместе с атрибутом `class`. Если требуется не установить значение атрибута `class`, **а модифицировать его**, добавив новое значение  список, классов или наоборот удяляя что-то из этого списка, при этом сохранив часть прошлого списка классов, то лучше это делать не с помощью  `setAttributes`, а стандартными средствами `classList.add()`.

ну а так, пока что самый короткий и прочтой вариант выглядит так (без setAttributes)

```
document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(function(element) {
    element.classList.add("align-top");
    element.setAttribute("scope", "col");
    element.setAttribute("role", "button");
})
```

Comment: попробую завтра на свежую голову

Comment: @ArtemGoodov - пишите если что

Comment: Ну нет.. "class" делать через `setAttribute` явно глупо.. А вдруг там еще как-то классы есть.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, спасибо вам конечно за оценку, но я так не считаю. Ваша претензия возможна и имела бы смысл, если бы она пошла в окончательный вариант. Смысл этого вопроса и ответа показать на конкретном примере как нужно думать, действовать и какими приемами пользоваться для того чтобы сократить и оптимизировать код. Указанный вами пример был показан как вариант возможного развития событий, призванный показать что для выполнения однотипных действий можно написать вспомогательную функцию.

Comment: Я показал пример и тут же написал что в данном кейсе он не имеет смысла и я не вижу смысла на нем подробнее останавливаться и развивать мысль, которая не будет использоваться в итоговом варианте.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, более того я в принципе не вижу ничего плохого в использовании данной функции вместе с классом.

Comment: Есть кейсы в которых ей будет пользоваться удобнее.  В том числе с классами. Что если классы, которые есть в этих элементах нам не нужны и нам нужно из удалить? Это не проблема функции. Она делает ровно то, что заявляет. В названии написано что она устанавливает значения атрибутов - она ровно то и делает. А вот если бы она там еще и классы добавляла - то в таком случае мы бы просто обманывали пользователя т.к. добавляли бы функционал, который "скрыт от глаз пользователя" и неочевиден. Тут же всё честно и я не вижу в этом никаких проблем.

Comment: Ответственность за выбор и использование той или иной функции целиком и полностью лежит на пользователе. Вносить в функцию какую-то магию, чтобы в конкретном месте было чуть удобнее, чтобы потом об это постоянно спотыкаться - порочная практика. И весь этот разговор имел бы еще смысл, если бы данный вариант пошел в работу и использовался в итоговом варианте. И называть это явно глупым, как минимум не очень умно с вашей стороны

Comment: @OliverPatterson, добавил дисклеймер с предупреждением. Это единственное что можно сделать в данном кейсе

Answer (score 1):

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) в отличии от [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) возврашает пустой [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) потому можно убрать проверку `if (elements)` цикл и так не запустится:

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll("th");

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].classList.add("align-top");
  elements[i].setAttribute("scope", "col");
  elements[i].setAttribute("role", "button");
}
```

Но я бы переписал ещё:

- `let` на `const`, чтобы не было соблазна его переопределять
- для простого перебора, обычный цикл на [for of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('th');

for (const element of elements) {
  element.classList.add('align-top');
  element.setAttribute('scope', 'col');
  element.setAttribute('role', 'button');
}
```

Comment: сорри, когда ответ появился - я уже свой дописывал

Comment: @МихаилРебров Тебе не за что извиняться)) И твой намного подробнее

Comment: мой еще и отметили.

Comment: те за старания тож плюсик

Comment: @МихаилРебров Взаимно)

Comment: спасибо за оперативный ответ

Comment: ты снова на охоту вышел? или так, заскочил ненадолго?)

Comment: @МихаилРебров Можно сказать, что возвращаюсь)) Я просто в отпуске был, в другой стране, чуть больше 2-х недель потому не заходил сюда. Просматривал с телефона иногда вопросы, но не охота бывало отвечать)